# Llenar tabla verticalmente con ITextSharp en C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy usando ITextSharp para crear pdf con tablas como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero llenarlas dinámicamente celda por celda

```
celda1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sistema de Direccion", _subtitulo));
                celda1.Colspan = 1;
                celda1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                celda1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                tabla.AddCell(celda1);
```

pero se me llena de forma horizontal, quisiera saber si hay una forma de llenar primera la primera columna, luego la siguiente y así llenar por columnas

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu fuente de información? Tenes varios `List<string>`?  se me ocurre una manera de hacerlo, pero va a depender de eso

Answer (score 1):

Hace tiempo tuve un problema relativamente similar, y para solucionarlo, use esta pregunta de [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811161/how-to-fill-a-pdfptable-column-by-column-instead-of-row-by-row-using-itext).

Habiendo dicho esto, un método para solucionar tu problema (asumiendo que tenes múltiples listas de `strings`), podría ser, crear un [`PdfpTable`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html) por cada columna, de esta manera, la tabla original, sólo tendría una fila, dentro de esa fila, cada celda sería una nueva tabla de una sola columna (para de esta manera, llenarla verticalmente)

Por ejemplo:

Suponiendo que tenemos dos listas de `string`

```
List<string> criticosA = new List<string> { "Critico A1", "Critico A2", "Critico A3" };
List<string> criticosB = new List<string> { "Critico B1", "Critico B2", "Critico B3" };

//Creo un path al azar
var temppath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();            
//Creo un documento..
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
//Creo un FileStream para el PdfWriter
var output = new FileStream(temppath, FileMode.Create);
//Creo el Writer.
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
//Abro el documento.
doc.Open();           

//Creo la tabla principal (la que defeinirá la cant de columnas)
PdfPTable tablaPrincipal = new PdfPTable(2);
//Creo una variable PdfpCell que usaré a lo largo del ejemplo.
PdfPCell cell;
//Creo otra PdfpTable (la que usaré para simular el comportamiento que buscas).
PdfPTable tablaColumna = new PdfPTable(1);
//Ahora recorro la primer lista de string para agregarlo a la primer columna.
foreach (string s in criticosA)
{                
    //Instancio la celda con una frase con el texto del string.
    cell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase(s) );
    //La agrego a la columna.
    tablaColumna.AddCell(cell);
}
//Por último agrego la "Columna" a la tabla real.
tablaPrincipal.AddCell(tablaColumna);
/*
    * A esta altura, tenemos algo como lo siguiente
    *  |Critico A1|
    *  |Critico A2|
    *  |Critico A3|
    *  
    *  A esta altura, terminamos con la columna 1, ahora sólo bastaría
    *  con repetir el método para llenar el resto de las columnas.
    *               
    *  
    */            
tablaColumna = new PdfPTable(1);             
foreach (string s in criticosB)
{
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(s));
    tablaColumna.AddCell(cell);
}
tablaPrincipal.AddCell(tablaColumna);
doc.Add(tablaPrincipal);
doc.Close();
```

El ejemplo, producirá un pdf como el siguiente:

[image: Captura del pdf generado]

De más está decir, que esto es un mero ejemplo, en vos quedará el automatizar este método para no necesitar hardcodearlo basado en como tenes presentada la información en tu caso puntual.

Reitero, la idea la saqué de [*esta pregunta*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811161/how-to-fill-a-pdfptable-column-by-column-instead-of-row-by-row-using-itext) en SOen